# Jquery slideUp and slideDown using Transit js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Now I'm using Jquery to achieve this effect, but the animation is not smooth

```
$("#slideToggle").click(function () {

    $('#contatti').slideUp();

});
```

and this for CSS

```
#contatti {
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p99FM/

Can someone put me in the right direction to obtain the same result with Transit?
Thanks :)

Comment: can you please show me your code(HTML) using http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p99FM/

Comment: use animation.css for all amazing css animation effect. here you can download http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 1):

Well i suggest you to go with `css3` transition property:

```
.slideup {
   width: 100%;
   height:0;
   -webkit-transition: height 2s;
   -moz-transition: height 2s;
   -o-transition: height 2s;
   transition: height 2s;
}
```

then in jQuery use `toggleClass()` method:

```
$("#slideToggle").click(function () {
    $('#contatti').toggleClass('slideup');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery Transit, I've had success setting the height and overflow dynamically, before the transition begins.

```
 $('.slide')
      .css('height', $alert.height())
      .css('overflow', 'hidden')
      .transition({height: '0px'});
```